# Can the LAG function return a single DATE value that is not NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing 3 columns [MONTHNAME], [MONTHSTART] and [MONTHEND].  For reporting, I need to group all prior months together but leave the current month grouped by weeks.  To do this I need to get the prior month's ending date.  Below is the query I am using and it works properly, but is there a better way of determining the prior month's ending date without creating a table or using CTE with the LAG function?  There was no way I found to get the LAG function to return a single value so I had to use the following.  Our month ending dates do not fall on the calendar month ending date so I am pulling the data from a custom calendar.

```
DECLARE @tblMonthEndingDates  TABLE
  ([MONTHSTART]   DATE
  ,[MONTHEND]     DATE
  )

INSERT INTO @tblMonthEndingDates
VALUES('01-01-2018', '01-26-2018'),
      ('01-27-2018', '03-02-2018'),
      ('03-03-2018', '03-30-2018'),
      ('03-31-2018', '04-27-2018'),
      ('04-28-2018', '06-01-2018'),
      ('06-02-2018', '06-30-2018'),
      ('07-01-2018', '07-27-2018'),
      ('07-28-2018', '08-31-2018'),
      ('09-01-2018', '09-28-2018'),
      ('09-29-2018', '10-26-2018'),
      ('10-27-2018', '11-30-2018'),
      ('12-01-2018', '12-31-2018')

DECLARE @dtTbl TABLE(RN   INT
                    ,MS   DATE
                    ,ME   DATE
                    );
INSERT INTO @dtTbl
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [MONTHSTART]) AS ROWNUM
      ,[MONTHSTART]
      ,[MONTHEND]
FROM @tblMonthEndingDates;

WITH cteDt
AS
(
SELECT d2.[MS]
      ,LAG(d1.[ME]) OVER(ORDER BY d1.[MS]) AS PRIORDT
      ,d2.[ME]
FROM @dtTbl d1
LEFT JOIN @dtTbl d2   ON d1.[RN] = d2.[RN] 
)

SELECT [PRIORDT]
FROM cteDt
WHERE [MS] <= GETDATE() AND [ME] >= GETDATE()
```

So for this month I would want 09-28-2018 as the return value which the query does, I just want to know if there is a better/shorter way of returning that value.

Comment: If you don't have one already, you should consider building a calendar table (and there's a ton of good information out there about how to do that). The table should include your company's fiscal calendar information for cross-reference. At my last job, we used a 4-5-4 calendar that started in February, and I joined to that table hundreds, if not thousands, of times.

Comment: Yes, I already have a custom calendar table.  I am just trying to determine based off of today's date what the prior month end date was.  For example, if 08-31-2018, 09-28-2018, 10-26-2018 are the ending dates and based on today's date I would want to return 09-28-2018.

Comment: Add a Boolean flag Is_Last_Day_Of_Month to your custom calendar table, and then you can just go `Select Date_Value from Custom_Calendar_Table Where Date_Value <= @My_Date_Param and Is_Last_Day_Of_Month = 1`.  Would that not work?

Comment: Is it `tblMonthEndingDates`? If it is, could you add the schema of that table to your post? From there, it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Brian every date in the table represents the last day of the month.

Comment: @Eric the schema has been added so copy, paste and play.

Comment: I posted an answer, but it relies on MONTHNAME, which has disappeared. :) Was I off-base?

Comment: Ahhh - I hadn't grok'd your example fully - sample data is SO helpful.  Given what you've just told us, wouldn't `Select max(MonthEnd) from @tblMonthEndingDates where MonthEnd <= GetDate()` work?

Comment: @Brian...yes sir, it has been a long day and I knew there had to be something that short and sweet.  Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as useful?

Comment: Prompting a good back & forth is worth a +1.

Comment: I edited my initial answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Select 
    Max(MonthEnd) 
From @tblMonthEndingDates 
Where MonthEnd <= GetDate()
```

That will give you the most recent MonthEnd date before or on today's date.  Obviously, if you need strictly before, you'd use < rather than <=

Comment: I am trying to get the prior month's ending date based upon today's date.  Also, our month ending dates do not always occur on the actual month end.  For instance, October 2018 month end date is 10/26/2018.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't realize from your question that you meant something other than "last day of the calendar month".

Answer (score 0):

I used this query to get the start and end dates for the last @n months. You can adapt to meet your needs.

```
declare @t table (SD date,ED date)
declare @i int = 0
 ,@SD date
 ,@ED date
 ,@datetoEval date
 ,@EOM date
 ,@n int = 60

while(@i<=@n)
BEGIN
 set @datetoEval = DATEADD(month,-1*@i,getdate())
 set @SD = cast(cast(month(@datetoEval) as varchar(2)) + '/1/' + cast(year(@datetoEval)  as varchar(4)) as DATE)
 set @ED = dateadd(day,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@SD))

 insert into @t
 values(@SD,@ED)

 set @i=@i+1
END

select * from @t
```

Comment: I need just the prior month's ending date from the table.  Also, our month ending dates to do not necessarily fall on the calendar month ending date, so the date has to be pulled from the custom table I update every year.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it. Last month ended the day before this one started.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, MONTHSTART) AS MONTHEND
FROM @tblMonthEndingDates
WHERE 
  GETDATE() BETWEEN MONTHSTART AND MONTHEND
```

Comment: That would work but the table contains multiple years so that query returns multiple results.  You can add to the where clause to look at the same year but then you start getting into more coding to decipher when Jan roles around and trying to look back at Dec.

Comment: <Facepalm> _Of course_ it has multiple years. How's the edit look?

Comment: Still won't work. The first & last few days of the month will get janky because of the fiscal calendar. Not giving up. New edit coming.

Comment: Last edit. But Brian's works just as well. Maybe even faster.